# How to follow in front of the number to hide the option data?

Tags: html

May I know how to follow in front of the number to hide the option data? I want to range 100-199 and 200-299 data are hidden.

Below the code is a sample:

```html
<select id="test">
  <option value="1">187-1 Johnson</option>
  <option value="2">310-3 David</option>
  <option value="3">213-1 Howard</option>
  <option value="4">520-6 Hash</option>
  <option value="5">199-6 Lark</option>
</select>
```

Hope someone can guide me to hide in front of the number are range 100-199 and 200-299. If success the output like the below the picture. Thanks.

[image: output 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that. That hide all options starts from 1 and 2, so(100-299 was hidden) but they all still alive. You can delete them from DOM just change `el.style.display='none'` to `el.remove()`. I hope, this code helps you, In case you don't understand something, you can ask me a question.

```js
let select = document.querySelector('#test').children
for ( let el of select){
  if (el.textContent.match(/^[12]/)) el.remove()
}
```

```html
<select id="test">
  <option value="1">187-1 Johnson</option>
  <option value="2">310-3 David</option>
  <option value="3">213-1 Howard</option>
  <option value="4">520-6 Hash</option>
  <option value="5">199-6 Lark</option>
</select>
```

Comment: if add more 300-399,400-499,500-599, the code like this el.textContent.match(/^[12345]/) right?

Comment: But your answer why show 187-1 Johnson in the option?

Comment: @JohnSoon yea, right. But better write `match(/^[1-5]/)`( that interval from 1 to 5 - 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Ok. Can you check your code why show 187-1 Johnson?

Comment: @JohnSoon hm, after changing value all be fine. If you use `remove()` all good without changing value. I think problem with the initial `select` value. Try to resolve it now

Comment: <option value="1" checked>  add checked to hide right?

Comment: Got other method to replace checked? because I am worried will check my function

Comment: @JohnSoon no need `checked`, that I test my code. Try snippet now. All work fine?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056145/how-to-remove-prefix-according-selected-range-of-number  Mr Dima Vak, can you help me which part I get the wrong in this question?